# Ajax request status 200, however there is an error

Tags: jquery

I read a lot of topic about this problem. I'm not alone, but I didn't read a good answer.
I have an ajax request with jquery. My response is ok (200), however there is an error with jquery.

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/route?'+str
console.log(url);
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  //dataType:"json",

  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);  
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error AJAX");
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

If I open my URL in my webbrowser, everything seem to be ok :

```
{"version": 0.3,"status":0,"status_message": "Found route between points","route_geometry": "i|lV_sdeAuzfh@e`mP|}fh@lrlP","route_instructions": [],"route_summary":{"total_distance":1630115,"total_time":23,"start_point":"","end_point":""},"alternative_geometries": [],"alternative_instructions":[],"alternative_summaries":[],"route_name":["",""],"alternative_names":[["",""]],"via_points":[[3.83957,11.49760 ],[3.83905,11.49980 ]],"hint_data": {"checksum":639660167, "locations": ["y3MCAAAAAADUAAAAHgAAAEi713xf8-s_1dsFAECLEQC", "r3MCAAAAAAAQAAAADwAAAOsLxO6CrOA_odsFAByMEQB"]},"transactionId": "OSRM Routing Engine JSON Descriptor (v0.3)"}
```

In Firebug, I can read :

```
Réponse
Content-Language    fr
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 23 Jun 2013 20:33:51 GMT
Server  WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Vary    Accept-Language, Cookie
Requête
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host    127.0.0.1:8000
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
```

I can't get out this problem. Can you tell me where is my mistake ?
There is always my "error" in firebug :

```
error AJAX
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
error
(an empty string)
```

My server will return "json", if I put the right content-type in response and in jquery, same error :

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/route?q=a&loc=3.839923...6665779&loc=3.839130971521939,11.499844431876904

200 OK
        27ms    
jquery.min.js (ligne 5)
ParamètresEn-têtes
Réponse
Content-Language    fr
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sun, 23 Jun 2013 20:49:49 GMT
Server  WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Vary    Accept-Language, Cookie
Requête
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host    127.0.0.1:8000
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
```

Thanks
Regards
Etienne

Comment: Yeah, I don't see an error either?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I add some lines about the error in firebug. Thanks.

Comment: Is the URL of the Ajax request from the same domain as your web page was loaded from?

Comment: Try using `localhost` as the domain `url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/route?'+str`

Comment: is this `{"version": 0.3,"status":0,"status_message": "Found ...g Engine JSON Descriptor (v0.3)"}` from above exactly the data where you get the error from? Background: this seems to be French with probably a lot of `,´,^, c-cedille etc and this stuff needs to be UTF-8 encoded in JSON!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at adding gzip headers .. Am on mobile so difficult to find the references but ther are other similar issues related to gzip response handling